# Increase performance of else-if chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, if-statement

I'm building my service on NodeJs.
I have a web-scraping function and I have to call different crawlers for different domains.

```
if (domain == "aaa.kr") result = await crawlAA(args.url)
else if (domain == "aaa.com") result = await crawlA(args.url)
else if (domain == "bbb.com") result = await crawlB(args.url)
else if (domain == "ccc.com") result = await crawlC(args.url)
else if (domain == "d.com") result = await crawlD(args.url)
else result = await crawlOthers(args.url)
```

Right now, I have about 10 `else if` clauses. However, I will need to add more than 50~100 `else-if`s and I am thinking this can be a problem in the future.

Are there any efficient way to handle string if-clauses?
Will primarily filtering by the starting alphabet help?

Comment: You could set up an object, where each domain points to a function `{"aaa.kr": () => {}, ...}`, and then await the returned function (you would need to handle the `else` case as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance is almost certainly not an issue here - there are no loops or nested loops, The issue here is the very WET code, if you have lots of `else`/`if`s.

Instead of having lots of standalone `crawl` functions, use an object indexed by the domain instead, eg:

```
const fns = {
  'aaa.kr': <code of crawlAA here>,
  'aaa.com': <code of crawlA here>,
  'bbb.com': <code of crawlB here>,
  // ...
};
```

Then find the appropriate function-value on the object when trying to find a `result`, and call it:

```
const fn = fns[domain];
const result = fn ? fn(args.url) : crawlOthers(args.url);
```